# Java конструкторы класс

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор

Есть класс у меня

```
public class ImageByteList {

    protected byte[] mByteList;
    private BufferedImage mImg;    
    private int mHeight;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mNumColors;      

    /** Создание из экземпляра объекта*/
    public ImageByteList(ImageByteList ibl){
        this.mImg = null;
        this.mByteList = ibl.mByteList;
        this.mHeight = ibl.mHeight;
        this.mWidth = ibl.mWidth;
        this.mNumColors = ibl.mNumColors;
    }
   ..
}
```

Вот так сработает? В конструкторе наследника будет доступ к protected-свойству аргумента родительского типа?

Answer (score 2):

Сработает. В конструкторе ребенка у вас будет доступ к  protected byte[] mByteList;

Если член (поле или метод) класса объявлен с модификатором `protected`, то он доступен не только внутри самого класса, но и внутри всех классов-наследников

Comment: Не то хотел узнать,уже проверил сам. Если в конструктор наследника пришел аргумент-родитель, то он имеет доступ к его протектед-свойствам.